# Modify dart2js output about deferred library

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, dart2js

I'm using Dart for a chrome extension.

I inject code via content_scripts option in the manifest.json

My injected code contains a deferred library.

So, when the code is injected, it trys to get deferred at the wrong url.

**Example**

- Dart file

```dart
library main;

import "test.dart" deferred as test;
```

- Dart2js output

```javascript
init.deferredLibraryUris = {test: ["main.dart.js_1.part.js"]};
init.deferredLibraryHashes = {test: ["g6AIAUZ7pet024iv7oMBZNj6w2A="]};
```

How can I do, maybe via a transformer, modify the output to get `chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID/PATH/main.dart.js_1.part.js` instead of `main.dart.js_1.part.js`

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but Chrome API has a function [`chrome.runtime.getURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL) specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you, I already know this function whom return in my example `chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID/PATH/main.dart.js_1.part.js`, yes it's useful, but it's in the js file that I need to put this path. I could do it manually or with a small script, but I don't really understand how the generated the good hash code. (from here https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/compiler/lib/src/deferred_load.dart#L72)

Answer (score 0):

I would need to verify but I think you can just append the part file to the main JS file. Since it's a Chrome extension that shouldn't be a problem (since you don't care for download time).